# Flutter add round app icon for android in VSCode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, icons

I added app-icons to my app for both iOS and Android. I watched this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpQenyqxTmw&ab_channel=LondonAppBrewery) and it is working so far. But the problem I have is that my Android Icon looks like this at the moment:

[image]

But the icon should fill the circle. In the tutorial it is shown how you can do it in Android Studio, but I am using **`VSCode`**.

I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything..

How can I get this done?

By the way, I am not using `flutter_launcher_icons` .

Comment: flutter_launcher_icons this plugin was created to save stress.... so use it

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga in their docs I don't see anything on how you can make it fill the same way you can do it as shown in the video. The video is actually quite easy, nothing fancy. I just need a way to get this done in VSCode.

Comment: @Chris did you solve this issue?

Comment: @RegularJo I actually ended up using the package mentioned above. Its been working perfectly fine so far

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't do it from vs code, it has to be done in android studio...
I have searched for an answer as well as I was stuck with this and ended up doing it in android studio.
If someone has a solution please share.

Answer (score -1):

Flutter has its own default icon for every app in its Android and Ios folder so there are few steps that I would like to show to change the app icon.

Head over to https://appicon.co/ and generate your own icon using icon image (the zip file contains two main folders android and Assets.xcassets)

For android: Go inside android\app\src\main\res in your flutter app and there paste the android folder content.

For IOS: Go inside ios\Runner in your flutter app and there paste the Assets.xcassets content

Restart your emulator or rebuild your application

Comment: I did exactly that. The problem is that my icon should fill the whole Android icon and should not be the square